# How to make an emulated console like Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, kotlin, console, containers

I'm currently coding on a small system and I wanted to ask how i can make a console like you have in Docker containers? Like a virtual machine

Im currently using Kotlin
Even if the solution is not in Kotlin, I would be very grateful if you tell me anyway

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you say a little more about what you're after and what you've already tried?  A Docker container is a wrapper around a process; it does not have a "console" and in this sense it is not "like a virtual machine".

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure what exactly you are after, but if you are interested in building a virtual machine or containers you can check this out:

https://blog.lizzie.io/linux-containers-in-500-loc.html

https://felix.engineer/blogs/virtual-machine-in-c